# Azure blob storage and security - Sarbanes Oxley requirements

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I can use my application as a proxy to control access to a file located in Azure blob storage as outlined in this SO post [Azure blob storage and security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165771/azure-blob-storage-and-security).

Is this sufficient to meet Sarbanes Oxley requirements for securing documents?

Answer (score 3):

Don't know what these requirements are, but Windows Azure Storage services comply with ISO 27001:2005 and SAS70. You can learn more on Security compliances of Windows Azure [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/trust-center/).

What you ask is a **legal** question which cannot be answered by a **tech** community. You have to search for a legal advice, providing information collected at the [Windows Azure Trust Center](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/trust-center/).

Check out the [FAQ section of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) to understand why it may not be the best place to ask your question in its current form. It is most likely that you will not get your answer here.